# carousel slider is not slide to img after the video is completed

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I designed a carousel slider with one img and one video From YouTube. what I want is slider transition for img is 5 sec and then slide to video and stop and play complete video and then again slide to img and repeat this approach.
Now slider working like img transition time is 5 sec and slide to video play complete video and not sliding img back to home section as I want.
That's my code please help he If you are good at this. please inform me if you need more details

```
<?php $hero=carbon_get_theme_option('herosection');if($hero){?>
<section class="herovideo">
  <div id="myCarouselmain" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <?php $herocount=0; foreach($hero as $item){?>
      <li data-target="#myCarouselmain" data-slide-to="<?php echo $herocount?>" class="<?php if($herocount==false){echo "active";}?>"></li>
      <?php $herocount++;}?>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <?php $herocount2=0; foreach($hero as $item){?>
      
        <?php   if($item['herovideo'] == false){?>
          <div class="carousel-item <?php if($herocount2==false){echo "active";}?>">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo $item['heroimage'];?>" alt="image slide">
  
          <div class="carousel-cap ">
            <h5><?php echo do_shortcode($item['herotitle']);?></h5>
    <p class="lore"><?php echo do_shortcode($item['herodesc']);?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo $item['herodescbtntxur1'];?>" class="btn btnhero"><?php echo $item['herodescbtntx1'];?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $item['herodescbtntxtxur2'];?>" class="btn btnhero 2nd"><?php echo $item['herodescbtntxtx2'];?></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } $herocount2++;}foreach($hero as $item){ ?>
    
<?php if($item['herovideo'] == true){?>
        <div class="carousel-item " id="myCarousel">
 
            
            <div id="moviesCarousel" class="carousel slide d-block col-lg-12" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
        <div class="carousel-inner d-block w-100 border-right-0 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="width=100;"> <!-- embed is used for responsive size regardless of device -->
          
            <div class="carousel-item d-block embed-responsive-item active">
                <iframe  id="katniss" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uLtGW2Aexjw?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&mute=1&rel=0&theme=light" style="width:100%;background-color:#fff;"allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            

            // When a slide occurs, pause the current iframe video that is playing
            // player.pauseVideo():Void - Pauses the currently playing video.
            // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls
            $('#moviesCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
                // The variable "players" contain each Youtube Player for each iframe video
                // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player
                // event.from - The index of the current video (before the slide occurs)
                //            - It is also the index of the corresponding player for the current video
                // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#events
                players[event.from].pauseVideo();
            });
        });

        // Start of snippet from: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        var players = []; // would contain 1 player for each iframe video
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
        {
            var allMovieIframes = document.getElementById("moviesCarousel").getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            for (currentIFrame of allMovieIframes)
            {
                players.push(new YT.Player(
                    currentIFrame.id, // the target iframe video, here it is  either katniss, rancho, or logan
                    { events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange } }
                ));
            }
        }
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) // triggered everytime ANY iframe video player among the "players" list is played, paused, ended, etc.
        {
            // Check if any iframe video is being played (or is currently buffering to be played)
            // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING)
            {
                // If any player has been detected to be currently playing or buffering, pause the carousel from sliding
                // .carousel('pause') - Stops the carousel from cycling through items.
                // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#methods
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel('pause');
            }
            else
            {
                // If there are no currently playing nor buffering videos, resume the sliding of the carousel.
                // This means that once the current video is in a state that is not playing (aside from buffering), either it was:
                //     1. paused intentionally
                //     2. paused as an effect of a slide
                //     3. video has ended
                //     4. wasn't totally played from the start
                //     5. and literally any form where the video timer isn't running ;)
                //     - then the carousel would now resume sliding.
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel();
            }
        }
        // End of snippet from Youtube iframe API
    </script>
        
        

      </div>

        <?php }
        ?>
  <?php }?>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Try `$('#moviesCarousel').carousel('cycle');` in your else condition on function `onPlayerStateChange`

Comment: try but don't work can you please send me exeat format maybe I'm doing this wrong